# Tem como selecionar várias tabelas com o começo do nome iguais?

Tags: php, mysql

Na base `base_suporte`, há as tabelas com o token do usuário e o token do suporte  `suporte_tokenUser_tokenSup`.
Na página do suporte geral, precisa aparecer todos os suportes, essa parte está finalizada e funcionando.

Porém na parte do cliente, o que abriu o suporte, como as tabelas de cada suporte tem o final diferente, tem como fazer uma seleção de `suporte_tokenUser` para pegar todas as tabelas com o token do usuário iguais?

Ex:

Token do Usuário é `78` e o token do suporte é `45246`, logo assim o nome da tabela será `suporte_78_45246`.

No painel do usuário com token 78, precisa mostrar todas as tabelas que correspondem com o começo `suporte_78` ou `suporte_78_`. Tem como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível filtrar o nome das tabelas passando um determinado termo. Para isso basta utilizar a query **[SHOW TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html)**

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE "suporte_78%"
```